# The names of Windows Tools items in the control panel changed to the name of their registry keys

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, control-panel

I installed Windows 11 on my laptop. Recently, the options available in Windows Tools in the control panel have been changed to the registry key name string. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Windows tools items]

Comment: I am not sure what you might have done but what you show is not normal Windows 11 Production or Insider.

Comment: I am not sure but I think this trouble happened after installing ExplorerPatcher

Comment: @user3123721 - Start by uninstalling it

Comment: I'm not sure if this problem existed before the ExplorerPatcher. Anyway, I uninstalled, but the problem did not go away.

Comment: Try a new Windows User Profile (Account). If the problem goes away in a new User Profile then your main Profile is damaged and the most practical repair is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: The user has no problem. But for some reasons, I cannot delete the current user and create a new one

Comment: At this point you need to reinstall Windows to fix the issue you have,

Comment: I understand something new about this. When I change the view, this problem is not a problem in most views. For example, there is a problem in tiles, but there is no problem in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try first to test Windows integrity by running the commands :

- [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
- [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)

If this doesn't help with the problem, the next step is to do a
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).
This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same
precautions.

If this also doesn't fix the problem, only a total reinstall of Windows
is left.